# Pass the content of several ranges into another sub

Tags: string, vba, range

I have the following code which I will need to pass on several ranges (rngSrc and rngTgt).

```
 Sub Con_CCC()

 Dim arr, rngSrc As Range, rngTgt As Range, rng As Range, cell As Range
 Dim c As ColorStop
 Dim isGreen As Boolean
 Dim e As Long

 Worksheets("Index Changes").Range("P7:P24").ClearContents

 Set rngSrc = Sheets("Output").Range("J13:J100")
 Set rngTgt = Sheets("Index Changes").Range("Y7")

  For Each cell In rngSrc
   isGreen = False
   On Error Resume Next
     With cell.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
     End With
     e = Err.Number
   On Error GoTo 0
   If e = 0 Then
     For Each c In cell.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
         arr = LongToRGB(c.Color)
         If arr(2) / IIf(arr(1) = 0, 1, arr(1)) > 1.25 And arr(2) / IIf(arr(3) = 0, 1, arr(3)) > 1.25 Then
            isGreen = True
            Exit For
         End If
     Next c
  Else
     arr = LongToRGB(cell.Interior.Color)
     If arr(2) / IIf(arr(1) = 0, 1, arr(1)) > 1.25 And arr(2) / IIf(arr(3) = 0, 1, arr(3)) > 1.25 Then isGreen = True
  End If
  If isGreen Then
     If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = cell.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2) Else Set rng = Union(rng, cell.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2))
  End If
Next cell

If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Copy: rngTgt.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

In essence I will need a sub which contains the following code only and then takes the different rngSrc and rngTgt set in my other sub's.

```
   For Each cell In rngSrc
    isGreen = False
    On Error Resume Next
     With cell.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
     End With
   e = Err.Number
  On Error GoTo 0
  If e = 0 Then
    For Each c In cell.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
     arr = LongToRGB(c.Color)
     If arr(2) / IIf(arr(1) = 0, 1, arr(1)) > 1.25 And arr(2) / IIf(arr(3) = 0, 1, arr(3)) > 1.25 Then
        isGreen = True
        Exit For
     End If
 Next c
Else
   arr = LongToRGB(cell.Interior.Color)
   If arr(2) / IIf(arr(1) = 0, 1, arr(1)) > 1.25 And arr(2) / IIf(arr(3) = 0, 1, arr(3)) > 1.25 Then isGreen = True
 End If
 If isGreen Then
 If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = cell.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2) Else Set rng = Union(rng, cell.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2))
End If
Next cell

 If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Copy: rngTgt.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

let's call your Sub after "DoIt"

```
Option Explicit

Sub doit(rngSrc As Range, rngTgt As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim arr, rng As Range
    Dim c As ColorStop
    Dim isGreen As Boolean
    Dim e As Long

    For Each cell In rngSrc
        isGreen = False
        On Error Resume Next
        With cell.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
        End With
        e = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        If e = 0 Then
            For Each c In cell.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
                arr = LongToRGB(c.Color)
                If arr(2) / IIf(arr(1) = 0, 1, arr(1)) > 1.25 And arr(2) / IIf(arr(3) = 0, 1, arr(3)) > 1.25 Then
                    isGreen = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c
        Else
            arr = LongToRGB(cell.Interior.Color)
            If arr(2) / IIf(arr(1) = 0, 1, arr(1)) > 1.25 And arr(2) / IIf(arr(3) = 0, 1, arr(3)) > 1.25 Then isGreen = True
        End If
        If isGreen Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = cell.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2) Else Set rng = Union(rng, cell.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2))
        End If
    Next cell

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Copy: rngTgt.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

then your "main" code will be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Con_CCC()
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngTgt As Range

    Worksheets("Index Changes").Range("P7:P24").ClearContents

    Set rngSrc = Sheets("Output").Range("J13:J100")
    Set rngTgt = Sheets("Index Changes").Range("Y7")

    doit rngSrc, rngTgt '<--| call your 'DoIt()' sub passing 'rngSrc' and 'rngTgt' ranges
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeweller89, did you get through it?

Comment: @Jeweller89, it'd be nice of you giving proper feedback to people trying at helping you. thank you